# Session file stored with different name

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have a script for a little chat feature, it uses a single session for everyone.  Everything looks weird in this code, but I'm allowed to just edit it not recreate it.

The script tries to open this weird "single session for everyone" using code below:

```
$name='PREFIX-'.md5(home_url());
session_id($name);
session_name($name);
session_start();
```

Everything looks fine on localhost (XAMPP, Windows, PHP 7.2.5), but when I tried to use it on shared hosting server (Linux, PHP 7.1.18) the session is saved with various names and I can't read it anymore using same `$name`.

I've printed everything in `ini_get( 'session.save_path')` with `print_r(scandir($dir))` but there is nothing like `sess_PREFIX-*` there and the `save_path` folder is growing by page refresh 3 files every time.

Comment: Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? Did you check the rest of the session settings - like if maybe the session is set to auto-start there already? (And why is this tagged `wordpress`?)

Comment: @04FS Im working on a Wordpress template, I've opened error reporting with `E_ALL` but got nothing on that, and `$_SESSION` is null before `session_start()` so I believe auto-start is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friends pointed out [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-strict-mode) which fixed my problem with random session_id.